# Create aggregate in postgres using C language

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-aggregate

I want to create user-defined aggregate in postgres by C language. Here are my code.
sql code：

```
CREATE FUNCTION res_tras_crimes_c(state_c, int64)
        RETURNS state_c
        AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'res_tras_crimes'
        LANGUAGE C
        IMMUTABLE 
        PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION finalize_trans_crimes_c(state_c)
        RETURNS ArrayType
        AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME'
        LANGUAGE C
        IMMUTABLE 
        PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE AGGREGATE reservoir_sampling_c(int64)
(
        sfunc = res_tras_crimes,
        stype = state_c,
        FINALFUNC = finalize_trans_crimes,
);
```

For C code:

```
typedef struct state_c
{
    int64 *reservoir;
        int32 poscnt;
        int32 reservoir_size; 
} state_c;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(res_tras);
Datum
res_tras(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

        //state_c *d1 = malloc(sizeof(state_c));
        //struct state_c st;
    //  st = (state_c *)PG_GETARG_DATUM(0);
        struct state_c *st = (state_c *)PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
        int64 newsample = PG_GETARG_INT64(1);
        if(st == NULL) {
            int64 r[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            int64 *a = r;
            st->poscnt = 1;
            st->reservoir_size = 100;
            st->reservoir = a;
        }
        if(st->poscnt <= st->reservoir_size){
            int32 p = st->poscnt;
            *(st->reservoir+p-1) = newsample;
            st->poscnt ++;

        }else{
            int32 pos = rand() % st->poscnt ; //0 - postcnt -1
            if(pos < st->reservoir_size){
                *(st->reservoir+pos) = newsample;
            }
            st->poscnt ++;
        }
        PG_RETURN_POINTER(st);
}


PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(finalize_trans);
Datum
finalize_trans_(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        struct state_c *st = (state_c *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    PG_RETURN_ARRAYTYPE_P(st->reservoir);
}
```

Can i pass my struct pointer in transition function? and I want to return ARRAYTYPE in final function. I don't konw how to deal with it. Colud you help me? Thanks！

I want to know how to deal the arraytype and struct in c language in postgres

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run your code, but that should work in principle. You would use `internal` as `STYPE` in `CREATE AGGREGATE` and as first argument to the state transition function.

You can look at the PostgreSQL source for an example: `array_agg` uses `internal` as `STYPE`, and you can look at the definition of the state transition function `array_agg_array_transfn` in `src/backend/utils/adt/array_userfuncs.c`.